# Перегрузка << (вывод коллекции в поток вывода) для вектора

Tags: c++, операторы, перегрузка-операторов, вектор

Не совсем понял как правильно перегружать << для вектора.

```
template<class T>
class MainVector 
{
  ...
  ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const MainVector vect); 
};

template<class T>
ostream &MainVector<T>::operator<<(ostream &os, const MainVector vect) {
os << vect.m_size << " - length " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < vect.m_size; i++) 
{
   os << vect.m_vek[i] << " - index of vector's element " << i << endl; 
}
return os;

int main() {

}
```

Выдает ошибку при компиляции что там где идет перегрузка << должен быть только 1 аргумент.

Может кто свой вариант предоставит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этот оператор должен быть объявлен вне класса.

```
template <class T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const MainVector<T> &vect);
```

Иначе его первым операндом неявно будет объект класса плюс еще два параметра, заданные явно. Естественно, что компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, так как этот оператор может иметь только два операнда, а не три.

Если есть необходимость, то вы можете объявить его как дружественную функцию класса.

Можно сделать следующим образом. В классе объявить функцию (закрытую или открытую) вида

```
std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const;
```

которая выводит в поток ваш вектор, а оператор тогда можно определить как

```
template <class T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const MainVector<T> &vect)
{
    return vect.out( os );
}
```